# Using jq, convert csv file to json, using csv filename as top level object name

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I need to convert a bunch of csv files to json, using bash and jq v1.6. (I can't use other scripting languages because of a restriction on what script types are allowed to run on the server). Neither JSON or jq are significant parts of my skillset.

I need to use the csv filename as the json object name, read the csv to get the fieldnames from the header, and do a bit of re-mapping to move "owner" to a list (array?) name.

So, take this:

```
serverset1.csv

location,category,ip,owner
set1rack1,webserver,127.0.0.1,Customer1
set1rack2,appserver,127.0.0.2,Customer1
set1rack1,webserver,127.0.0.3,Customer2
set1rack2,appserver,127.0.0.4,Customer2
```

to this

```
[
   {
      "serverset1":[
         {
            "Customer1":[
               {
                  "location":"set1rack1",
                  "category":"webserver",
                  "address":"127.0.0.1"
               },
               {
                  "location":"set1rack2",
                  "category":"appserver",
                  "address":"127.0.0.2"
               }
            ],
            "Customer2":[
               {
                  "location":"set1rack1",
                  "category":"webserver",
                  "address":"127.0.0.3"
               },
               {
                  "location":"set1rack2",
                  "category":"appserver",
                  "address":"127.0.0.4"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I got as far as this:

```
filename="serverset1.csv"; \
cat "$filename" | jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output \
'
  split("\n") | .[1:] | map(split(",")) |
    map(
         {
            "location": .[0],
            "category": .[1],
            "address": .[2],
            "owner": .[3]
         }
    )
'
```

which yields this:

```
[
  {
    "location": "set1rack1",
    "category": "webserver",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "owner": "Customer1"
  },
  {
    "location": "set1rack2",
    "category": "appserver",
    "address": "127.0.0.2",
    "owner": "Customer1"
  },
  {
    "location": "set1rack1",
    "category": "webserver",
    "address": "127.0.0.3",
    "owner": "Customer2"
  },
  {
    "location": "set1rack2",
    "category": "appserver",
    "address": "127.0.0.4",
    "owner": "Customer2"
  }
]
```

but then I hit a syntax wall.

Any help is appreciated.

~Jaimie

Answer (score 2):

Use `input_filename` to get the input filename. To skip the first line, use `inputs` without the -n option:

```
jq -R '
  inputs
  | [splits(", *")] as $row
  | {(input_filename): { ($row[3]): $row[:3] }}
' serverset1.csv
```

This produces a stream of the "filename" objects, which you can then readily assemble into an array by modifying the script (rather than invoking jq a second time).

If the input file has no header, then use the -n command-line option.

#### Caveats

1. jq can read very simple CSV files but is not well-suited to reading CSV files in general.  If your CSV file cannot easily be read properly by jq, you could use one of the many excellent alternatives for converting a CSV to a TSV file.
2. The above program does not attempt to convert numeric or boolean strings to JSON numbers or boolean values; any such conversions can however easily be accomplished using jq by making the appropriate tweaks to the above program.

Comment: The script seems to put header in the result as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. OP seems to want the first json as result but your script generates the second json.

Comment: Thank you. This worked a treat to handle the the filename. The rest clicked after that.

Comment: Well, it almost worked. After a bit closer review...

Comment: I thought I had it... but I didn't... 
The proposed solution outputs the filename repeating at each level...
I really need it to have the filename inserted once at the top level, as shown above...

Comment: This was all left as an exercise.  The big question is: are the input lines already grouped by customer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. 
The CSV snippet provided is just a tiny sample of the data format I have to work with. 
The real data is composed of several hundred files, 18 to 22 columns per file, each with several hundred to several thousand records. Not all columns are populated, but all records have a populated "owner" field. I do have access to "sort", "column" and "cut", so I could merge/rewrite the files to a single consistently formatted mega-file, if that would be required.

Comment: It sounds as though you might need to rethink your problem from an engineering point of view.

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping that using something like jq would make it easier, but this may simply be outside of the programs scope.

Comment: Functionally, it's not outside jq's scope, but you might want to use an external `sort` program because jq's sorting and grouping operations are in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample input, the following produces the requested output:

```
# The -n option is omitted in order to skip the header
jq -R '
  reduce inputs as $in ({};
   (input_filename | sub("[.]csv$";"")) as $file
   | ($in | [splits(", *")]) as $row
   | {location: $row[0], category: $row[1], address: $row[2]} as $obj
   | .[$file][$row[3]] += [$obj])
| [ . ]
' serverset1.csv
```

Additional files can be specified on the command line.

The above could easily be modified if it is desired to generate the key names based on the header.